# Scientist discovers hyperspace with a twist

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hyperspace

I believe the setting is an Earth that desperately needs transportation to the stars (overpopulation?)

A scientist discovers hyperspace (I believe he solves a theory that explains how to reach it, but I am not certain). However, he can't get any government agency to believe him and fund his research. Furthermore, government agencies are funding wacky other [FTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light) drives with little chance of success.

Finally, one government representative agrees to see the scientist. The government representative explains that hyperspace was already solved, but that speeds in hyperspace were *slower*, not faster than those in normal space.

I read this more than 10 years ago and probably more like 20. It was a short story, probably in an anthology book.

Comment: @jimb - Glad you liked the answer!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is "FTA" by George RR Martin, originally published [Analog Science Fiction](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50960) in 1974.

As per the description [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SQMQQyIaACYC&pg=PA405&lpg=PA405&dq=george%20rr%20martin%20FTA&source=bl&ots=O0gu6jcgCk&sig=fVdr-J52wrncX4FVgxpVldgM-Sw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7u8NVYiFJc_iaq3IgtAG&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=george%20rr%20martin%20FTA&f=false), the twist ending is that hyperspatial travel is basically useless.

- **Scientist is upset that they're funding other FTL avenues;**

> Schechter sighed again. “You’re working under several
> misapprehensions. To begin with, the FTL Foundation was created to
> research a method of faster-than-light travel. A star drive, let us
> say. Hyperspace is only one avenue toward that end. Right now, we’re
> pursuing other avenues that look more promising. We …” **“I know all
> about those other avenues,” Kinery interrupted. “Dead ends, all of
> them. You’re wasting the taxpayers’ money. And my God, some of the
> things you’re funding! Allison and his teleportation experiments.
> Claudia Daniels with her nonsense about an esper-engine. And Chung’s
> time-stasis hypothesis!**

- **Twist ending is that hyperspace is useless:**

> Schechter cut him off. “Never mind,” he said. “It isn’t important. We
> fund the crackpot theories that we fund because they’re better than
> nothing. Hyperspace is the dead end, Kinery. We keep the myth alive
> for the public, but we know better.” Kinery grimaced. “Oh, come now,
> Schechter. Take a look at my papers. You give me the funding and I’ll
> give you a hyperspace engine within two years.” Schechter turned to
> face him. “I’m sure you would,” he said, in a voice infinitely weary.
> “You know, Canferelli once said there was no reason why the limiting
> velocity of light should apply in hyperspace. He was right. It
> doesn’t. “I’m sorry, Kinery. Really I am. But **Lopez gave us a
> hyperdrive thirty years ago. That’s when we discovered that the
> limiting velocity in hyperspace is not the speed of light. “It’s
> slower, Kinery. It’s slower.”**

Comment: A similar theme is seen in Redshift Rendezvous, a space opera where hyperspace travel is measured in mph.

Comment: Excellent response - very thoroughly answered!

Comment: @Jim2B - We exist but to serve.